# Laravel - Rota "insegura"

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, uuid

Estou fazendo uma função para avaliar a uma transação entre um cliente (empresa) e o cliente dele (consumidor final). Aí é enviado um email/sms para o consumidor final com um link para ele avaliar a transação rapidamente pelo celular mesmo. Pensei em fazer o url cair direto na transação sem pedir login, mas para ter um mínimo de segurança, pensei em identificar essa transação no link pelo UUID ou HashMd5 de alguns dados dessa informação.

Quais seriam os prós e contras de cada solução?
Qual é o melhor pacote para UUID em laravel mesmo ou para php geral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução que eu adoptei recentemente, para não ter tantos passos do lado do utilizador foi:

1. Produz o link para o consumidor final associado à transação e com timestamp
2. O cliente recebe um link com uma HASH. Usei SHA1 com email, um salt (palavra random fixa) e id único calculado no momento e guardado no perfil.
3. Executa um JOB paralelo que verifica todos os hash criados há mais de 1 dia. Ai pode criar um novo hash e relembrar ou simplesmente apagar.
4. Clica no link e valida o HASH

Para o salt com id tem a função uniqid() do php que o pode ajudar.